# Ошибка типизации TypeORM

Tags: node.js, typescript, nestjs, typeorm

Пытаюсь сделать запрос в бд с помощью typeorm таким образом:

```
@Injectable()
export class AppService {
  async checkExistenceUser(data: any): Promise<any> {
    const IUsers = new Users();

    const user = await getConnection()
      .createQueryBuilder()
      .select('nickname')
      .from(IUsers, 'users')
      .where('users.nickname = :nickname', {
        nickname: data.nickname,
      })
      .getOne();
  }
}
```

Но в строке from, подключенный entity Users выдает такую ошибку:

[image: Ошибка]

Сам entity:

```
@Entity('users')
export class Users extends BaseEntity {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;

  @Column()
  nickname: string;

  @Column()
  password: string;

  @CreateDateColumn()
  registration_date: number;
}
```

Подскажите в чем проблема.
На всякий случай прикладываю ссылку на [репозиторий](https://github.com/MrYogurt/chat-app)

Upd: Поставил any при создании инстанса Users:

```
const IUsers: any = new Users();
```

Получил ошибку:

[image: Ошибка 2]

Я так понимаю у меня и запрос неправильный, хотя копировал его из доков.

Answer (score 0):

Я пропустил объявление репозитория в сервис классе:

```
constructor(
    @InjectRepository(User)
    private usersRepository: Repository<User>,
  ) {}
```